# NHibernate 2 HQL not working

Tags: c#, exception, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I have a basic console application in which i using NHibernate V2.x to learn it. It is configured with FluentHibernate. I am facing a strange exception when executing the hql query to get all the users from user table. I know that user is reserved keyword,

so i tried `SELECT * FROM [User]` and it worked good with `CreateSqlQuery` method but then below failed miserably with the exception

`Method 'HasAncestor' in type 'NHibernate.Hql.Ast.ANTLR.Tree.ASTNode' from assembly 'NHibernate, Version=2.1.2.4000, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=aa95f207798dfdb4' does not have an implementation.`

which is also referred [here](https://nhibernate.jira.com/browse/NH-3407). Below is all that i have in my console application, could you point out what is wrong

```
            ISessionFactory factory = CreateSessionFactory();

            //read using HQL the 500 users
            using (ISession dbSession = factory.OpenSession())
            {
                var users = dbSession.CreateQuery("from user").List();
            }
```

Dropbox Link to Solution ( Source + Database + Configuration ]

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/29815170/HQL.zip

note: Please do change your database connections inside the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would almost for sure say, that this is the lower/upper case issue. The HQL parser *(the ANTLR engine)* results in case sensitive statements. Because, in C# we use Pascal style for Class names, I would say that your class is **User**.

HQL is working on top of Entity/C# model. So this should/must be working:

```
var users = dbSession.CreateQuery("from User").List(); // U is in capital
```

Comment: I don't think so, HQL was not intended to be used for `2.1.2.4000` I believe, I upgraded to `V3` and it works awesome. Never touched a line in my code. I will have to stick to **SQL with CreateSqlQuery** that's all i can do

Comment: Please, you do not think so, or you tried? I tested localy, and the User or user is the issue. Simply HQL is on top of the Enitty model... user is uknown

Comment: Wait a second... If you solved that... not a problem. What I am saying is, that `from user` would never work, even in NHiberante 3.+ because it is most-likely not mapped. The only mapped class, I expect is the User *(But anyhow... upgrade is the **only** correct solution anyway. v2 is really very old)*

Comment: I haven't found solution why HQL does not work with V2 even though many examples + docs says so. May be i am doing something wrong. I have included Dropbox link to the Solution, it includes database script and working code. Just have to run it

Comment: OK, I've got it. All is I've told you: (also you can check here: 14.1. Case Sensitivity http://nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#queryhql-casesensitivity). So the problem of your shown code was the case "u" vs "U". But the problem of your example is different. NHibernate 2.1 was using different version of ANTLR then you are. I have NHibernate 2.1 package containing the Reuqired dll. I guess it is still downloadable. If you use this library, and remove the runtime remapping in your code... you can check that all is working

Comment: Here you can get the zip http://sourceforge.net/projects/nhibernate/files/NHibernate/2.1.0.GA/ with the correct antlr inside. In app config remove the assemblyBinding and reference this version. It will work ;) I do enjoy NHibernate

Comment: You ROCK +1, I did arrive at solution when i got to know Antlr is the one that parses HQl, so it must be upgraded Simple bit this needs to be specified some where i Believe